# Maximise the difference in the number of occurrences of the most and the least frequent letter in the fragment of a string

Tags: algorithm

This is a  [question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/STC04/) from spoj

> A word consisting of N lower-case letters of the English alphabet ('a'-'z') is given. We would like to choose a non-empty contiguous (i.e. one-piece) fragment of the word so as to maximise the difference in the number of occurrences of the most and the least frequent letter in the fragment. We are assuming that the least frequent letter has to occur at least once in the resulting fragment. In particular, should the fragment contain occurrences of only one letter, then the most and the least frequent letter in it coincide.

Example:

> Input
>
> - 10
> - aabbaaabab
>
> Output
>
> - 3

I have a approach if there are only two letters (say a & b)
1) counter initialized to zero.
2) Now traverse the string from left to right, for each occurrence of `a` increment counter and for each occurrence of `b` decrement the counter.
3) The absolute difference of maximum and minimum values of the counter gives the solution.

Now I can extended this approach by checking for every pair of `a` & `b` which makes my algorithm running time  `26 * 26 * length of string`.I should take care of the case where I get a substring with only one character separately. But this running is not sufficient for the current problem. How can I optimise my algorithm or is there a better algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand how your approach works for 2 letters. E.g. What does it do with the string `baaaabaaaab`? (The answer is 7 for the substring `aaaabaaaa`)

Comment: @Rob Minimum is -1 and Maximum is 6

Comment: Why isn't the maximum 7 (8-1)? I.e. omit the 1st and last characters? Or do your fragments have to be prefixes of the string?

Comment: The maximum is 7.I still get the same substring. maximum (=6) occurs at 10th character and minimum(=-1) occurs at 2nd character. The required string is between maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small optimisation would be to keep track of all 26*26 counters (1 for each pair of letters) during a single pass through the string.

The advantage of this is that when you read the character, you only need to update the pairs that correspond to the letter.

In other words, you are updating 26*2 counters instead of 26*26 so the running time is more like 2 * 26 * length of string.

Another possible optimisation is that you may be able to reduce the number of counters by only tracking pairs a & b if a < b.  The counter for b,a will always be the negative of the counter for a,b.

Overall I would hope these two changes should reduce your running time by a factor of around 26.